# Category listing in magento2 in custom page

Tags: magento2

I wanted to create a custom page having all categories listed with checkbox and on click of that products should get filtered. Can anybody suggest how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea:

We are using [Multiple Select in Layered Navigation von Manadev](https://www.manadev.com/advanced-layered-navigation-ce). There you get a Category filter which you may use.

Otherwise you may have a look at a Collection Filter as described [here](https://webkul.com/blog/product-collection-category-magento2/).

It would be quite easy to get a select with all your categories with category_id as option. Then you built your request.